# How to merge my working branch to main branch as main branch revert?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

If I checkout a branch `a` from main branch, and I have made many changes on `a` branch. But the main branch revert some commits for some reasons. How can I merge `a` branch's changes to main branch the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) from `main` the revert commits done on `main`, to apply the same revert on `a`.

```bash
git switch a
git cherry-pick <commitSHA1-from-main> # a commit representing a revert
```

Then you can make a regular merge from a to `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) in interactive modes and remove the undone commits.

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git pull`
3. `git checkout a`
4. `git rebase -i master`

Remove the deleted commits in the following view with d and then save them.

```
d 38608aa remove commit from master
d f23afss remove commit from master
pick 183b5fg first commit from a
pick fasde6e second commit from a
```

After that, you can merge branch a to master.